# How to insert data in table using cursor in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor, sql-insert

In this procedure I want to insert `userid` value is different like in this  select query we have insert all data.

Contents of `T_ALLOCATIONCONFIG` table:

```
 id   userid   customerid   subbatchtypeid
---- -------- ------------ ----------------
 1    29       10003        1
 1    30       10003        1
```

Contents of `VW_BATCH` table:

```
 batchid   batchname   subbatchtypeid   customerid   batchstatus_id
--------- ----------- ---------------- ------------ ----------------
 1         test        1                10003        1
 2         test1       1                10003        1
 3         test2       1                10003        1
 4         test3       1                10003        1
 5         test4       1                10003        1
 6         test5       1                10003        1
 7         test6       1                10003        1
 8         test7       1                10003        1
 9         test8       1                10003        1
 10        test9       1                10003        1
 11        test12      1                10003        1
```

I want this type of result in `T_BATCHALLOCATION` table:

```
 id   batchid   customerid  userid
---- --------- ----------- --------
 1    1         10003        29
 2    2         10003        29
 3    3         10003        29
 4    4         10003        29
 5    5         10003        29
 6    6         10003        30
 7    7         10003        30
 8    8         10003        30
 9    9         10003        30
 10   10        10003        30
```

Suppose we have 10 record from vw_batch, so I want to insert 5 records with `userid = 29` and 5 records with `userid = 30` in `batchallocation` table.

How to write query or store procedure to insert this kind of result?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_autoallocate_batches
AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE
      --      v_coll_rules_id coll_rules.coll_rules_id%TYPE;
      v_customer_id t_customers.customer_id%TYPE;
      v_batchid     t_batch.batchid%TYPE;
      v_user_id     t_users.user_id%TYPE;
      c             types.cursortype;

      CURSOR c_aa IS
       SELECT b.customer_id,
              b.batchid,
              a.user_id
        FROM vw_batch b
        JOIN t_allocationconfig a
          ON a.customer_id = b.customer_id
         AND a.subbatchtypeid = b.subbatchtypeid
       WHERE b.batchstatus = 'New' AND a.isactive = 'Y';

    BEGIN
      -- Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Hello World');
      -- Insert Into Tmp (Column1) Values ('Started');

      OPEN c_aa;

      LOOP
        FETCH c_aa INTO v_customer_id, v_batchid, v_user_id;
        EXIT WHEN c_aa%NOTFOUND;

        IF (v_customer_id > 0 AND v_batchid > 0 AND v_user_id > 0) THEN
          INSERT INTO t_batchallocation (customer_id, batchid, user_id, created_by, created_date)
          VALUES (v_customer_id, v_batchid, v_user_id, 1, sysdate);

          UPDATE t_batch
          SET batchstatus_id = 2, modified_by = 1, modified_date = sysdate
          WHERE batchid = v_batchid;
        END IF;

        --Insert Into Tmp (Column1) Values ('Started123');

        COMMIT;
      END LOOP;

      CLOSE c_aa;

    END;
  END;
```

Comment: Do you really need to do it in **PL/SQL**? I think you could do it in one step in pure **SQL** using a **MERGE** statement.

Comment: Please give me example using MERGE .Yes i need in oracle sql developer

Comment: SQL Developer is a tool. SQL is a language. Anyway, just search the site for MERGE statement, you will get plenty of examples.

Comment: You have two different tables for insert and update? Them merge won't work for different tables.

Comment: Get rid of the explicit cursor, instead use a **cursor for loop** which will be efficient as under the hood it would do a `bulk collect limit 100`.

Comment: Also, add the checks for customer_id >0 etc. in the where clause of the query. No need to check them afterwards.

Comment: @DipalKothari so you want to spread the users in the t_allocationconfig table amongst the rows in the vw_batch rows? So, if there were 3 users in t_allocationconfig and 12 rows in vw_batch (presumably for the same customer and subbatchtype), each user would have 4 rows? What happens if the rows don't spread evenly? I.e. in your example, suppose there were 11 rows; which user should be assigned the "extra" row?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use cursors to do this - you could do it in two sql statements like so (but you'll have to create a type to hold the batch_ids that were inserted):

```
create type num_list as table of integer;

create or replace procedure p_autoallocate_batches
as
  v_batch_ids num_list;
begin
  insert into t_batchallocation (customer_id,
                                 batchid,
                                 user_id,
                                 created_by,
                                 created_date)
  select b.customer_id,
         b.batchid,
         a.user_id,
         1,
         sysdate
  from   vw_batch b
         inner join t_allocationconfig a on (a.customer_id = b.customer_id
                                             and a.subbatchtypeid = b.subbatchtypeid)
  where  b.batchstatus = 'New'
  and    a.isactive = 'Y'
  and    b.customer_id > 0
  and    b.batchid > 0
  and    a.user_id > 0
  returning batchid bulk collect into v_batch_ids;

  update t_batch
  set    batchstatus_id = 2, modified_by = 1, modified_date = sysdate
  where  batchid in (select * from table(v_batch_ids));

  commit;

end p_autoallocate_batches;
/
```

N.B. untested, as you didn't provide table definitions or sample data

Also, I'm not sure I answered your original question, since I didn't understand it. Please alter your question to provide some sample data in your tables and what you want to be inserted in tabular format.

---

Ok, following the additional information added into your question, I *think* the following will do what you're after:

```
with t_allocationconfig as (select 1 id, 29 userid, 10003 customerid, 1 subbatchtypeid from dual union all
                            select 1 id, 30 userid, 10003 customerid, 1 subbatchtypeid from dual),
               vw_batch as (select 1 batchid, 'test' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 2 batchid, 'test1' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 3 batchid, 'test2' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 4 batchid, 'test3' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 5 batchid, 'test4' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 6 batchid, 'test5' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 7 batchid, 'test6' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 8 batchid, 'test7' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 9 batchid, 'test8' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 10 batchid, 'test9' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual union all
                            select 11 batchid, 'test12' batchname, 1 subbatchtypeid, 10003 customerid, 1 batchstatus_id from dual)
--end of mimicking your sample data - see SQL below:
select vb.batchid id, -- is id supposed to be derived using a sequence, perhaps?
       vb.batchid,
       vb.customerid,
       ta.userid
from   (select id,
               userid,
               customerid,
               subbatchtypeid,
               row_number() over (partition by id, customerid, subbatchtypeid order by userid) rn,
               count(*) over (partition by id, customerid, subbatchtypeid) cnt
        from   t_allocationconfig) ta
       inner join (select batchid,
                          batchname,
                          subbatchtypeid,
                          customerid,
                          batchstatus_id,
                          row_number() over (partition by customerid, subbatchtypeid order by batchid) rn,
                          count(*) over (partition by customerid, subbatchtypeid) cnt
                   from   vw_batch) vb on (ta.customerid = vb.customerid
                                           and ta.subbatchtypeid = vb.subbatchtypeid
                                           and ta.rn = ceil(vb.rn/ceil(vb.cnt/ta.cnt)));

        ID    BATCHID CUSTOMERID     USERID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1      10003         29
         2          2      10003         29
         3          3      10003         29
         4          4      10003         29
         5          5      10003         29
         6          6      10003         29
         7          7      10003         30
         8          8      10003         30
         9          9      10003         30
        10         10      10003         30
        11         11      10003         30
```

This means that your code should look something along the lines of:

```
-- make sure you have a global type:
create type num_list as table of integer;

create or replace procedure p_autoallocate_batches
as
  v_batch_ids num_list;
begin
  insert into t_batchallocation (customer_id,
                                 batchid,
                                 user_id,
                                 created_by,
                                 created_date)
  select vb.customerid,
         vb.batchid,
         ta.userid,
         1,
         sysdate
  from   (select id,
                 userid,
                 customerid,
                 subbatchtypeid,
                 row_number() over (partition by id, customerid, subbatchtypeid order by userid) rn,
                 count(*) over (partition by id, customerid, subbatchtypeid) cnt
          from   t_allocationconfig) ta
         inner join (select batchid,
                            batchname,
                            subbatchtypeid,
                            customerid,
                            batchstatus_id,
                            row_number() over (partition by customerid, subbatchtypeid order by batchid) rn,
                            count(*) over (partition by customerid, subbatchtypeid) cnt
                     from   vw_batch) vb on (ta.customerid = vb.customerid
                                             and ta.subbatchtypeid = vb.subbatchtypeid
                                             and ta.rn = ceil(vb.rn/ceil(vb.cnt/ta.cnt)))
  returning batchid bulk collect into v_batch_ids;

  update t_batch
  set    batchstatus_id = 2, modified_by = 1, modified_date = sysdate
  where  batchid in (select * from table(v_batch_ids));

  commit;

end p_autoallocate_batches;
/
```

N.B. You may have to play around with the `partition by` and join clauses to make sure that the data is grouped and joined on the right columns - I took a guess as to what the logic was behind that, since you didn't say. Hopefully, you'll be able to deconstruct the query to see what it's doing, and amend as appropriate!

Comment: thx boneist for your reply but it cannot solve my problem i read you don't understand my problem so i could edit my question if you know then pls reply its very urgent

Comment: You need to provide the corresponding data from your vw_batch, along with the data you're expecting to see. Remember that we can't see your screen, so if you want us to help you, you'll need to provide as much info as possible so we can replicate your data etc and run queries against it.

Comment: @DipalKothari I've updated my answer to include the SQL statement that I believe does what you're after, assuming that I've understood your requirements of course! Thanks for adding the information into the question - it makes it much easier for us to see what you're trying to achieve!